# Host usercontrol in datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, user-controls

I am trying to host a usercontrol in a datagridview cell.

I use the How-To article from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

It works properly. But when I use my usercontrol that contains a textbox and a button, the cell value does not get updated with the value from the textbox in the user control.

I change the code...

class CalendarEditingControl : DateTimePicker,

To...

class CalendarEditingControl : MyUserControl,

The usercontrol does get displayed when then cell is in edit mode, but the value of the textbox does not update the cell value.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Here is the CalendarEditingControl...

```
class CalendarEditingControl : nsFinances.Design.Centres.Account_Registers.Controls.Amount, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    DataGridView dataGridView;
    private bool valueChanged = false;
    int rowIndex;

    public CalendarEditingControl()
    {
        //this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        this.Width = 75;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue  
    // property. 
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get
        {
            //return this.Value.ToShortDateString();
            return this.AmountValue;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is String)
            {
                //try
                //{
                //    // This will throw an exception of the string is  
                //    // null, empty, or not in the format of a date. 
                //    this.Value = DateTime.Parse((String)value);
                //}
                //catch
                //{
                //    // In the case of an exception, just use the  
                //    // default value so we're not left with a null 
                //    // value. 
                //    this.Value = DateTime.Now;
                //}

                this.AmountValue = (string)value;
            }
        }
    }

    // Implements the  
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method. 
    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
        DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {

        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }

    // Implements the  
    // IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method. 
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
        DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
        //this.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
        //this.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex  
    // property. 
    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return rowIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            rowIndex = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey  
    // method. 
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
        Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed. 
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit  
    // method. 
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        // No preparation needs to be done.
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property. 
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingControlDataGridView property. 
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get
        {
            return dataGridView;
        }
        set
        {
            dataGridView = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingControlValueChanged property. 
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return valueChanged;
        }
        set
        {
            valueChanged = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingPanelCursor property. 
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Cursor;
        }
    }


    //protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
    //{
    //    // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell 
    //    // have changed.
    //    valueChanged = true;
    //    this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    //    //base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
    //}
}
```

Comment: What makes you to think user control doesn't displayed. I just did and it displays usercontrol.

Comment: Show us your implementation of `CalendarEditingControl`.

Comment: The user control does display, but the current cell does not get updated when I move off that cell.

Answer (score 0):

I read the remarks on Microsoft Site it reads:
The formatted value represents the value as it is displayed in the control's user interface. **The formatted value may be different in absolute value and even data type from the actual value contained in the control.**